# Voting icons cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The edge of the upvote/accepted answer icon are cut off slightly on one side. Note the left sides of the active upvote icon and accepted answer icon (blown up to make it more apparent):

[image]
And the left side of the inactive upvote icon:

[image]

The icon also moves over at least one pixel when it's clicked, which I think is why the cut off changes sides. But the circle isn't "perfectly" round in either graphic.

Comment: +1 for hand drawn circles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, the sprite position information in the CSS was off in a few spots. Fixed now, thanks.